# JavaFX 8: primaryStage cannot be resolved

Tags: java, javafx-2

JavaFX primaryStage is not working. Why? I checked in google but I havent found anything related to the type of issue. I mean the library is set up. I imported javaFX and wrote this class but again it doesnt work and I have no idea where to start to solve this problem. Im new to Java.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("The Noob Project");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A variable needs to be defined before it can be used. Try this

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("The Noob Project");
    // add controls to the stage...
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, your `primaryStage` is actually being passed in as `arg0`. I'd recommend changing the `arg0` to `primaryStage`.